# How to make a <ul> always stick to the top of the browser page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, positioning

I have a `<ul>` at the top of the page showing navigation items. Currently its positioned via position:absolute to stick in place. Code:

```
#navigation
{
    text-align: center; 
    position: absolute; 
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 110px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What I want to do, is to have this navigation bar remain glued to the top of the screen, and not be affected by the user's scrolling underneath the page. Kind of like this page:

http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/products.html#drive

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried using "fixed" instead of absolute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the position to "fixed"

```
#navigation {
    text-align: center; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none; }
```

Comment: This works great, but what happens is, the content runs 'through' the navigation menu now when i scroll the content.

Comment: I want the content to always stay below the navigation bar. Now, even though the navigation bar is fixed to the top of the page, the content can move over the navigation bar. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Try setting the z-index on the #navigation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 2):

use `top` and `left` property:

```
#navigation
{
    text-align: center; 
    position: absolute; 
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

You also could try to set the `fixed` position and set the `z-index` with a value greater than the other elements. The divs inside this `#navigation` have to be `position: relative` to get the same behaviour.